# Zoom on an area of a image map

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, imagemap

I'm currently trying to make a responsive image map where we can also zoom on specific areas.

For the moment I have something like that (illustration):

[image: image map]

I have for example 3 sections for 3 different area but now what I wan't is to zoom in a specific area when the user click on it. I already tried a few jquery script but the problem is that it zoom everything and the area don't resize by themselves (but when we reduce the window, it does).

I would like something like that:
http://preview.codecanyon.net/item/mapplic-custom-interactive-map-jquery-plugin/full_screen_preview/6275001?redirect_back=true&ref=coolansh63

When you click on it, it just zoom where you want to go.

For now here is the code that I have:

https://jsfiddle.net/brch3rn9/

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Mapify/src/mapify.scss">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css2.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div>
        <img id="test" src="flag.png" alt="" usemap="#Map" height="500px" width="488px"/>
    </div>

    <map name="Map" id="Map">
        <area alt="" title="1" id="TXXX" href="#" shape="poly" coords="355,72,362,422,475,435,472,83"/>
        <area alt="" title="2" id="TXX" href="#" shape="poly" coords="190,463,357,471,345,67,184,81"/>
        <area class="1" alt="" title="3" id="TX"  href="#" shape="poly" coords="87,438,187,459,181,78,12,98"/>
    </map>

    <footer>            
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="Mapify/src/mapify.js"></script>

        <script>
            $("img[usemap]").mapify({
            popOver: {
                content: function(zone){ 
                    return "<strong>"+zone.attr("data-title")+"</strong>";
                },
                delay: 0.7,
                margin: "15px",
                height: "130px",
                width: "260px"
            }
        });
        </script>
    </footer>
</body>
```

EDIT : I manage to make a zoom with the mouse wheel but now there is another problem, the map area doesn't resize and thus, they get offset. Is there any way to zoom where the user click only?

Comment: Can you set up a fiddle/codepen of what you have so far? Thanks

Comment: Demo is done using svg. Image map is not nearly as robust as using svg and for that reason isn't used a lot any more

Comment: Sorry for the delay I added a link : https://jsfiddle.net/brch3rn9/ and I will probably be using an SVG (I'm just preparing for a project). The thing is that I don't know if it will change a lot of things and I can't spend to much time (10 day).

Comment: did you got any solution?